# Why request.get_full_path is not available in the templates?

Tags: python, django

I am currently passing `'request_path': request.get_full_path()` through `render_to_response`. I was wondering is this is really nessccary since I was told the it's unnesscary and the context processor takes care of that but {{ get_full_path }} is empty.

Please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add [`django.core.context_processors.request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) in your template context processors settings which is [not there by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors) and render the response with `RequestContext`. Like

```
return render_to_response('my_template.html', 
                        my_data_dictionary,  
                        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This will add `request` variable in your template, then you can use `{{ request.get_full_path() }}` in a template.

Answer (score 4):

Try `{{ request.get_full_path }}` in your template.