# Django set_language function redirects to site root although next parameter is defined

Tags: python, django, nginx, translation, django-i18n

I am using `django.views.i18n.set_language()` redirect view and HTML form where user can choose language. 
I am doing everything as it's described in [Django documentation for i18n translation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#set-language-redirect-view) .
The only difference that I made is that within HTML form I changed value of next parameter from `{{redirect_to}}` to `{{request.get_full_path}}`

Anyway, It worked completely fine while I was testing it locally. I could select different language and it would reload current page but with different language.

Now I put application on VPS where I use Gunicorn as application server and Nginx as web server. Now when I select different language it still changes it but it always redirect me to to home page / (site root).

I have no idea why is that happening now and how to change it. I want that he reloads the same page again instead of redirecting me to the / always. Anyway, at translation still works fine.

Thank you for your replys

Kind regards

Comment: Are you sure request.get_full_path is available in the template? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392423

Comment: Yes, you are right, I cannot believe I couldn't see that before. I updated my template context processors with requests and now it works fine. I still don't know why it worked locally before when I didn't have those processors there either but nevermind, now it's ok. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wander Nauta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182402/wander-nauta) answered it in the comments

> Are you sure request.get_full_path is available in the template?

You need to add [`django.core.context_processors.request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) in your template context processors settings, which is [not there by default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-context-processors).